# Turn based game center displays the state of game incorrect when offline

Tags: ios, game-center

I am using iOS 6 Game Center API for turn based games.

When the device is disconnected from internet
In the completion handler of the method

```
[currentMatch endTurnWithNextParticipant:nextParticipant matchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);

        } else {
            //save the new state of the game
        }
```

I get an error. But then, game center standard UI that displays matches list, says "Their turn". when connected again it changes to "Your turn".

The code from famous tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/5509/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-2 has the same exact problem.

How I should handle this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem . did you get solution for this issue? . If you got please post the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using iOS 6 Game Center API then you will have to use

```
-endTurnWithNextParticipants:turnTimeout:matchData:completionHandler:
```

because...

```
–endTurnWithNextParticipant:matchData:completionHandler: Deprecated in iOS 6.0
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This won't solve the original problem, however. It will only make the game dependant on iOS6 and above. Ideally, you should decide at runtime, whether to call the new one or the deprecated one, depending on what version of iOS your game is running on (4.3/5.x or 6.x)

Answer (score -1):

The thing is, that when you use GC methods that change status of the match (`matchData` and synchronization info in this case), data is uploaded to the GC server so that other player(s) get the update. If you're disconnected and ignore the error, your local `GKTurnBasedMatch` and its `matchData` change, as well as your synchronization info (which is used to determine if it is your turn to act among other things).

However, since you are diconnected, only your local instance of `GCTurnBasedMatch` is updated (you get error so that you app is aware of that). When you're reconnected, your app authenticates the user and updates match state (if you're following the tutorial code). Updating match data reverts the sync data (so it's still your turn).

At this point, you should either submit the turn again (provided that you cached `gameData` that was passed to GC while you were disconnected) and/or call `updateMatchData` so that your local `GKTurnBasedMatch` and its `matchData` get in sync with what's on the server. You should also re-layout your game board with previous turn's data if you didn't re-submit turn after reconnection.